# JMeter Test Not Executing script when parametrized using csv file

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have tried to parametrize from a csv file using the steps mentioned in this [link](http://apache-jmeter.blogspot.in/2011/12/parameterization-using-csv-data-set.html).

While executing it is showing the following error

> `Response code: Non HTTP response code:
>    org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException Response message: Non
>    HTTP response message: Connection to http://www.redbus.in:8080
>    refused`

I have given port as 8080 and changed the browser settings also accordingly. Without parametrization the code is working fine. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like that you need to change your port to `80`.

In regards to CSV parametrization, the most common error is incorrect placement of [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) element. In the majority of cases it should go **as a child** of sampler, you intending to parametrize.

Comment: the issue was with the placement of CSV config element.

Answer (score 1):

Link provided http://www.redbus.in:8080/ is **not giving any response** while using a browser. But http://www.redbus.in/ showing the web page. My suggestion is try to record your scenario using  Test script recorder then parameterize the values.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the problem is, it's not related to the CSV data set config. You need to identify the specific change you made that's making the script not work. You probably made a few changes to the script when trying to make it work with a CSV file.

Try taking your working script (the one without the data set config) and make small incremental changes and **see if it works every time you make ANY change.**